# Hudson sourcesafe Plugin problem

Tags: hudson, visual-sourcesafe

i have a question. I use VSS (SourceSafe) Plugin in Hudson. But I don't have rights for a file. If I start my job, I have the following error: "Access to file ... denied" and Hudson stops the build. How can I ignore this error and continue the build ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: What file is this? Is it a source file? What is the file used for in terms of VSS?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics, you will have to tell Visual SourceSafe to ignore that file for the specific user being used so that the file isn't retrieved when the job is started. Otherwise, you will have to get the necessary permissions to retrieve the file. I doubt there is anything you can do in Hudson to prevent the build from failing.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in configuration allows you to specify the user that accesses the SourceSafe repository. Normally what you should do is create a CI/build user and use that information to get access to any files involved in the build.

You can verify the user has access by attempting to open the 'srcsafe.ini' file over the network using that same information. If it works, you should be able to retrieve files from VSS via Hudson. If it doesn't, then you'll have to poke around more in your environment.

Basically, just make sure you can get things running manually first using the same account information before you try and integrate your build into Hudson.